# Get full command line from process

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I have the process ID (*PID*), how can I get its full command line (path and arguments)?

[image: Task manager]

Comment: @CherryDT I saw it now: I can't "translate" C++ to Delphi but I found `NtQueryInformationProcess` interesting, it looks like it does what I need but in [MS documentation it says it might be deprecated in future versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to do this; needed to terminate known applications, perform a task, then restart them with the same command line parameters they started with.

Of all the methods that I explored that can achieve getting command line parameters for each running process, WMI proved to be the safest and least painful way.

Add the 2 units pasted below, then call `GetProcessList()` and loop through the objects in the `TObjectList`. In your application, ensure you call `CoInitialize(nil)` on start up, and `CoUninitialize()` before it's closed. Code tested in Delphi 6.

```
unit uWmi;

interface

uses
  Classes, Contnrs,
  Variants, ActiveX, ComObj;

const
  WMI_RESULT_OK = 0;
  WMI_RESULT_NO_RECORDS = 1;
  WMI_RESULT_NULL = 2;
  WMI_RESULT_INVALID_PROPERTY = 3;
  WMI_RESULT_ERROR_EXEC_QUERY = 4;
  WMI_RESULT_UNKNOWN_ERROR = 5;

  WMI_RESULT_STRINGS: array [0..5] of string = (
    'OK',
    'No records',
    'Property value is null',
    'Invalid property',
    'Error executing query',
    'Unknown error'
  );

type
  TWmi = class
  private
    FService: OleVariant;
    function ExecWmiQuery(const AWMIQuery: string; var AItems: OleVariant; var AEnum: IEnumVariant): Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create;
    
    class function GetWmiObject(const objectName: string): IDispatch;
    class function GetWmiSelectQuery(const AWMIClass: string; const ASelectAll: Boolean; const AWMIProperties: TStrings = nil; const AWMIProperty: string = ''): string;
    class function GetWmiPropertyValue(const AItem: OleVariant; const AProperty: string; var AValue: string): Integer;

    class procedure AddWmiPropertyValueToList(const AValue: string; AResult: Integer; AValues: TStrings); overload;
    class procedure AddWmiPropertyValueToList(const AItem: OleVariant; const AProperty: string; AValues: TStrings); overload;

    function GetFirstRecordSinglePropertyValue(const AWMIClass, AWMIProperty: string; var AValue: string;
      const ASelectAll: Boolean): Integer; overload;
    function GetFirstRecordSinglePropertyValue(const AWMIProperty: string; var AValue: string;
      const AWMIQuery: string): Integer; overload;      

    function GetAllRecordsSinglePropertyValues(const AWMIClass, AWMIProperty: string; AValues: TStrings;
      const ASelectAll: Boolean): Integer; overload;
    function GetAllRecordsSinglePropertyValues(const AWMIProperty: string; AValues: TStrings;
      const AWMIQuery: string): Integer; overload;

    function GetAllRecordsMultiplePropertiesValues(const AWMIClass: string; AProperties: TStrings;
      ARecords: TObjectList; const ASelectAll: Boolean): Integer; overload;
    function GetAllRecordsMultiplePropertiesValues(AProperties: TStrings; ARecords: TObjectList;
      const AWMIQuery: string): Integer; overload;

    function GetAllRecordsMultiplePropertiesValues(const AWMIClass: string; const AProperties: array of string;
      ARecords: TObjectList; const ASelectAll: Boolean): Integer; overload;
    function GetAllRecordsMultiplePropertiesValues(const AProperties: array of string;
      ARecords: TObjectList; const AWMIQuery: string): Integer; overload;
  end;
  
implementation

uses
  SysUtils, uStringUtils;

const
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;

{ TWmi }

function TWmi.ExecWmiQuery(const AWMIQuery: string; var AItems: OleVariant; var AEnum: IEnumVariant): Boolean;
begin
  try
    AItems := FService.ExecQuery(AWMIQuery, 'WQL', wbemFlagForwardOnly);
    AEnum := IUnknown(AItems._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
    Result := True;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

 
constructor TWmi.Create;
{$IFDEF USE_LOCATOR}
const
  USER = '';
  PASSWORD = '';
  COMPUTER = 'localhost';
var
  locator: OleVariant;
{$ENDIF}
begin
  {$IFDEF USE_LOCATOR}
  locator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FService := locator.ConnectServer(COMPUTER, 'root\CIMV2', USER, PASSWORD);
  {$ELSE}
  FService := GetWmiObject('winmgmts:\\localhost\root\cimv2');
  {$ENDIF}
end;

class function TWmi.GetWmiObject(const objectName: string): IDispatch;
var
  chEaten: Integer;
  BindCtx: IBindCtx;
  Moniker: IMoniker;
begin
  OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx));
  OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, Moniker));
  OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindCtx, nil, IDispatch, Result));
end;

class function TWmi.GetWmiSelectQuery(const AWMIClass: string; const ASelectAll: Boolean;
  const AWMIProperties: TStrings = nil; const AWMIProperty: string = ''): string;
var
  props: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  if ASelectAll then
    props := '*'
  else
    if AWMIProperties = nil then
      props := AWMIProperty
    else
      for i := 0 to AWMIProperties.Count - 1 do
        if props = '' then
          props := AWMIProperties[i]
        else
          props := props + ',' + AWMIProperties[i];

  Result := Format('SELECT %s FROM %s', [props, AWMIClass]);
end;

class function TWmi.GetWmiPropertyValue(const AItem: OleVariant; const AProperty: string; var AValue: string): Integer;
var
  v: OleVariant;
begin
  try
    v := AItem.Properties_.Item(AProperty).Value;
  except
    Result := WMI_RESULT_INVALID_PROPERTY;
    AValue := '';
    Exit;
  end;

  if VarIsNull(v) then
  begin
    Result := WMI_RESULT_NULL;
    AValue := '';
    Exit;
  end;
  
  AValue := Trim(v);
  Result := WMI_RESULT_OK;
end;

class procedure TWmi.AddWmiPropertyValueToList(const AValue: string; AResult: Integer; AValues: TStrings);
begin
  AValues.AddObject(AValue, TObject(AResult));
end;

class procedure TWmi.AddWmiPropertyValueToList(const AItem: OleVariant; const AProperty: string; AValues: TStrings);
var
  value: string;
  r: Integer;
begin
  r := GetWmiPropertyValue(AItem, AProperty, value);
  AddWmiPropertyValueToList(value, r, AValues);
end;

function TWmi.GetFirstRecordSinglePropertyValue(const AWMIClass, AWMIProperty: string; var AValue: string;
  const ASelectAll: Boolean): Integer;
begin
  Result := GetFirstRecordSinglePropertyValue(AWMIProperty, AValue,
    GetWmiSelectQuery(AWMIClass, ASelectAll, nil, AWMIProperty));
end;

function TWmi.GetFirstRecordSinglePropertyValue(const AWMIProperty: string; var AValue: string;
  const AWMIQuery: string): Integer;
var
  items, item: OleVariant;
  enum: IEnumVariant;
  value: Cardinal;
begin
  try
    if not ExecWmiQuery(AWMIQuery, items, enum) then
    begin
      Result := WMI_RESULT_ERROR_EXEC_QUERY;
      Exit;
    end;

    if enum.Next(1, item, value) <> 0 then
      Result := WMI_RESULT_NO_RECORDS
    else
      try
        Result := GetWmiPropertyValue(item, AWMIProperty, AValue);
      finally
        item := Unassigned;
      end;
  except {on: EOleException do Writeln(e.Source, ' ', e.ErrorCode, ' ', e.Message);}
    Result := WMI_RESULT_UNKNOWN_ERROR;
  end;
end;

function TWmi.GetAllRecordsSinglePropertyValues(const AWMIClass, AWMIProperty: string; AValues: TStrings;
  const ASelectAll: Boolean): Integer;
begin
  Result := GetAllRecordsSinglePropertyValues(AWMIProperty, AValues,
    GetWmiSelectQuery(AWMIClass, ASelectAll, nil, AWMIProperty));
end;

function TWmi.GetAllRecordsSinglePropertyValues(const AWMIProperty: string; AValues: TStrings; const AWMIQuery: string): Integer;
var
  items, item: OleVariant;
  enum: IEnumVariant;
  value: Cardinal;
begin
  try
    if not ExecWmiQuery(AWMIQuery, items, enum) then
    begin
      Result := WMI_RESULT_ERROR_EXEC_QUERY;
      Exit;
    end;
    AValues.Clear;    
    while enum.Next(1, item, value) = 0 do
      try
        AddWmiPropertyValueToList(item, AWMIProperty, AValues);
      finally
        item := Unassigned;
      end;

    if AValues.Count = 0 then
      Result := WMI_RESULT_NO_RECORDS
    else
      Result := WMI_RESULT_OK;
  except {on: EOleException do Writeln(e.Source, ' ', e.ErrorCode, ' ', e.Message);}
    Result := WMI_RESULT_UNKNOWN_ERROR;
    AValues.Clear;
  end;
end;

function TWmi.GetAllRecordsMultiplePropertiesValues(const AWMIClass: string; AProperties: TStrings;
  ARecords: TObjectList; const ASelectAll: Boolean): Integer;
begin
  Result := GetAllRecordsMultiplePropertiesValues(AProperties, ARecords,
    GetWmiSelectQuery(AWMIClass, ASelectAll, AProperties));
end;

function TWmi.GetAllRecordsMultiplePropertiesValues(AProperties: TStrings; ARecords: TObjectList;
  const AWMIQuery: string): Integer;
var
  items, item: OleVariant;
  enum: IEnumVariant;
  value: Cardinal;
  values: TStrings;
  i: Integer;
begin
  try
    if not ExecWmiQuery(AWMIQuery, items, enum) then
    begin
      Result := WMI_RESULT_ERROR_EXEC_QUERY;
      Exit;
    end;

    ARecords.Clear;
    while enum.Next(1, item, value) = 0 do
      try
        values := TStringList.Create;
        ARecords.Add(values);
        for i := 0 to AProperties.Count - 1 do
          AddWmiPropertyValueToList(item, AProperties[i], values);
      finally
        item := Unassigned;
      end;

    if ARecords.Count = 0 then
      Result := WMI_RESULT_NO_RECORDS
    else
      Result := WMI_RESULT_OK;
      
  except {on: EOleException do Writeln(e.Source, ' ', e.ErrorCode, ' ', e.Message);}
    Result := WMI_RESULT_UNKNOWN_ERROR;
    ARecords.Clear;
  end;
end;

function TWmi.GetAllRecordsMultiplePropertiesValues(const AWMIClass: string; const AProperties: array of string;
  ARecords: TObjectList; const ASelectAll: Boolean): Integer;
var
  props: TStringList;
begin
  props := CreateStringList(AProperties);
  try
    Result := GetAllRecordsMultiplePropertiesValues(AWMIClass, props, ARecords, ASelectAll);
  finally
    props.Free;
  end;
end;

function TWmi.GetAllRecordsMultiplePropertiesValues(const AProperties: array of string;
  ARecords: TObjectList; const AWMIQuery: string): Integer;
var
  props: TStrings;
begin
  props := CreateStringList(AProperties);
  try
    Result := GetAllRecordsMultiplePropertiesValues(props, ARecords, AWMIQuery);
  finally
    props.Free;
  end;
end;

{initialization
  CoInitialize(nil);
finalization
  CoUninitialize;}

end.
```

```
unit uWmiProcess;

interface

uses
  Contnrs;

type
  TProcessInfo = class
  public
    Name: string;
    ProcessId: Cardinal;
    ExecutablePath: string;
    CommandLine: string;
    SessionId: Integer;
    CreationDate: string;
  end;

function GetProcessList: TObjectList{<TProcessInfo>};

implementation

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, uWmi;

function GetProcessList: TObjectList{<TProcessInfo>};
var
  wmi: TWmi;
  processInfo: TProcessInfo;
  records: TObjectList;
  values: TStringList;
  i: Integer;

  function CallWmi(const AProps: array of string): Boolean;
  begin
    Result := wmi.GetAllRecordsMultiplePropertiesValues('Win32_Process', AProps, records, False) = uWmi.WMI_RESULT_OK;
  end;

begin
  Result := TObjectList.Create(True);
  try
    records := TObjectList.Create(True);
    try
      wmi := TWmi.Create;
      try
        if not CallWmi(['Name', 'ProcessId', 'ExecutablePath', 'CommandLine', 'SessionId', 'CreationDate']) then
          Exit;

        for i := 0 to records.Count - 1 do
        begin
          processInfo := TProcessInfo.Create;
          Result.Add(processInfo);

          values := TStringList(records[i]);

          processInfo.Name := values[0];
          processInfo.ProcessId := StrToInt(values[1]);
          processInfo.ExecutablePath := values[2];
          processInfo.CommandLine := values[3];
          processInfo.SessionId := StrToInt(values[4]);
          processInfo.CreationDate := values[5];
        end;
      finally
        wmi.Free;
      end;
    finally
      records.Free;
    end;
  except
    //FreeAndNil(Result);
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;

end.
```

```
unit uStringUtils;

interface

uses
  Classes;

procedure SplitString(const ASource: string; const ASeparator: Char; AValues: TStrings); overload;
function SplitString(const ASource: string; const ASeparator: Char): TStringList; overload;
function JoinStrings(const ASeparator: string; AValues: TStrings): string;
function CopyRange(const ASource: string; const AIndexFrom, AIndexTo: Integer): string;

type
  TStringsHelper = class //poor man's helper :) ToDo should be other way around, naked routines calling the static class?
  public
    class procedure SplitString(const ASource: string; const ASeparator: Char; AValues: TStrings); overload;
    class function SplitString(const ASource: string; const ASeparator: Char): TStringList; overload;
    class function JoinStrings(const ASeparator: string; AValues: TStrings): string;
  end;

type
  TStringArray = array of string;

procedure FillStringList(const AValues: array of string; AStrings: TStrings);
function CreateStringList(const AValues: array of string): TStringList;
function CreateStringArray(const AStrings: array of string): TStringArray;

implementation

function CopyRange(const ASource: string; const AIndexFrom, AIndexTo: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := Copy(ASource, AIndexFrom, AIndexTo - AIndexFrom + 1);
end;

procedure SplitString(const ASource: string; const ASeparator: Char; AValues: TStrings);
var
  i, lastDelimPos: Integer;
begin
  AValues.Clear;
  lastDelimPos := 0;

  for i := 1 to Length(ASource) do
    if ASource[i] = ASeparator then
    begin
      if lastDelimPos = 0 then
        AValues.Add(CopyRange(ASource, 1, i - 1))
      else
        AValues.Add(CopyRange(ASource, lastDelimPos + 1, i - 1));
      lastDelimPos := i;
    end;

  if lastDelimPos = 0 then
    AValues.Add(ASource)
  else
    AValues.Add(CopyRange(ASource, lastDelimPos + 1, MaxInt));
end;

function SplitString(const ASource: string; const ASeparator: Char): TStringList;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  SplitString(ASource, ASeparator, Result);
end;

function JoinStrings(const ASeparator: string; AValues: TStrings): string;
var
  s: string;
  i, len: Integer;
  p: PChar;
begin
  case AValues.Count of
    0:
      Result := '';
    1:
      Result := AValues[0];
    else
      len := (AValues.Count - 1) * Length(ASeparator);
      for i := 0 to AValues.Count - 1 do
        Inc(len, Length(AValues[i]));

      SetLength(Result, len);
      p := PChar(Result);

      for i := 0 to AValues.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if i = 0 then
          s := AValues[i]
        else
          s := ASeparator + AValues[i];
        Move(PChar(s)^, p^, Length(s));
        Inc(p, Length(s));
      end;
  end;
end;

{ TStringsHelper }

class procedure TStringsHelper.SplitString(const ASource: string;
  const ASeparator: Char; AValues: TStrings);
begin
  uStringUtils.SplitString(ASource, ASeparator, AValues); //Note the explicit unit reference
end;

class function TStringsHelper.SplitString(const ASource: string;
  const ASeparator: Char): TStringList;
begin
  Result := uStringUtils.SplitString(ASource, ASeparator); //Note the explicit unit reference
end;

class function TStringsHelper.JoinStrings(const ASeparator: string;
  AValues: TStrings): string;
begin
  Result := uStringUtils.JoinStrings(ASeparator, AValues); //Note the explicit unit reference
end;

procedure FillStringList(const AValues: array of string; AStrings: TStrings);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  AStrings.Clear;
  AStrings.Capacity := Length(AValues);
  for i := 0 to Length(AValues) - 1 do
    AStrings.Add(AValues[i]);
end;

function CreateStringList(const AValues: array of string): TStringList;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  FillStringList(AValues, Result);
end;

function CreateStringArray(const AStrings: array of string): TStringArray;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(AStrings));
  for i := 0 to Length(AStrings) - 1 do
    Result[i] := AStrings[i];
end;

end.
```

Comment: I doubt very much that this code even compiles with Delphi 6, because it uses Generics which Delphi 6 didn't support. Maybe you mean Delphi XE6?

Comment: It's not generics, it's curly braces you're seeing

Comment: Also note that on Windows Vista and newer you might have to run your application with Elevated privileges in order to get command line information of other applications

Comment: Before posting my question I also saw a few references to WMI, is it _always_ available and active on all Windows systems? Can it be used without admin privileges?

Comment: Ouch! Yes, it's a comment TObjectList{<TProcessInfo>} (curly braces) rather than a Generic TObjectList(<TProcessInfo>) (parentheses). My eyes definitely got worse over the years. Thanks @TByte for pointing that out.

Comment: @MarinaFinetti I've not encountered instances where WMI didn't exist/work. It worked fine for me on XP, Windows 7 (32 and 64 bit) and Windows 10 (32 and 64 bit). I found WMI to be surprisingly reliable and useful (e.g. I've added CreationDate recently for a different task). I've used this class for 3 different projects, big and small, so I can vouch for the stability of WMI and the above code, but that's just been my experience, someone else with more authority/understanding might say otherwise.

Comment: Regarding admin privileges: you will have missing fields for elevated processes if you don't start your application with admin privileges. You will get similar results if you used EnumProcesses + OpenProcess API's. However, results from those API's are affected by whether the calling process has debugging privileges. Additionally, OpenProcess with PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION (not on XP) flag can squeeze more out of that method - in my tests only 3 processes (excluding PID of 0) had missing information with that flag. ....

Comment: I only took those API's as far as getting the process file path + name, not command line. The ideas for this online, using PEB and reading from process memory etc; a lot more involved and I didn't see a completely working version anywhere (covering 32bit, 64bit and WoW combinations). My code above is missing a little bit of extra stringlist related crap, just adding that now.

Comment: Added the missing uStringUtils code. Nothing fancy, just stuff that works in Delphi 6.  @Remy: thank you very much for cleaning up my answer!

Comment: @dummzeuch no worries!!! it's a silly thing to do, sneaking in comments that look like Generics syntax :) Can I be a pain and point out that TObjectList(<TProcessInfo>) is not a valid declaration? :)

Comment: Da**, you got me again. @TByte

Comment: [How do I get the command line of another process?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091125-00/?p=15923)

Comment: @RemyLebeau good post, definitely worth a read for those attempting to get command line data from other processes. Yes indeed, no matter the method of obtaining it, the command line data can be intentionally or inadvertantly changed or overwritten. It's perfectly suitable for my needs though, the applications I am shutting down and restarting are all known to me (either my own or a known third-party). As far as I am concerned, there appears to be no other way to restart applications with the same command line parameters they were started with, so I accept/take any command line data I can get.